# A multi-input PySimpleGUI for a working python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, f5, pysimplegui

I'm using a working script built in python 3 that reads an excel file. Using the input, it figures out which VIP (Virtual IP) subnet I should use and which F5 load balancer the VIP should be matched with, and then spits out the cli commands needed to configure on the load balancer as another file. I want to know if it's possible to add a basic GUI to this using the code I have below. Based on that, it will create a file on my desktop with the commands I need to configure taken from the excel file and input given. If the information is blank within excel it will prompt and ask you. An edited example of a simple working script that runs is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress, IPSet
import os
import glob
import shutil


def createfolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory. ' + directory)


global options
global member
global lb_mode
global pool_member1
global pool_member2
global pool_member3
global pool_member4
global cert
global iRule1
global iRule2
global rules
global one_connect
global http_profile
global primary_persist
global fallback_persist
global snat
global rule_member_1
global rule_member_2
global rule_member_3
global irules
global profiles
global loadbalancer
global subnet
global ssl_profile_name
global ssl_config

x = datetime.datetime.now()
change_order = input("What is the change order for this VIP? ")
lbarf_file = str(input("Enter the full path of the LBARF form. ").strip('\"'))
description = "description " + change_order
df = pd.read_excel(lbarf_file)

# Info pulled from the LBARF
service_port_input = str(df.iloc[13, 2])
http_profile_input = df.iloc[33, 2]
primary_persist_input = df.iloc[34, 2]
fallback_persist_input = df.iloc[35, 2]
iRule1_input = df.iloc[42, 2]
iRule2_input = df.iloc[43, 2]
snat_input = df.iloc[47, 2]
one_connect_input = df.iloc[48, 2]
fqdn = str(df.iloc[12, 2]).lower()
member1 = str(df.iloc[19, 2])
member2 = str(df.iloc[20, 2])
member3 = str(df.iloc[21, 2])
member4 = str(df.iloc[22, 2])
pool_port1 = str(df.iloc[19, 4])
pool_port2 = str(df.iloc[20, 4])
pool_port3 = str(df.iloc[21, 4])
pool_port4 = str(df.iloc[22, 4])
lb_mode_input = df.iloc[32, 2]
pool_name = str(fqdn + "-" + pool_port1)
monitor_input = df.iloc[36, 2]

# Pool builder
if member1 == "nan":
    pool_member1 = ""
elif member1 != "nan":
    pool_member1 = member1 + ":" + pool_port1 + " "
else:
    pass
if member2 == "nan":
    pool_member2 = ""
elif member2 != "nan":
    pool_member2 = member2 + ":" + pool_port2 + " "
else:
    pass
if member3 == "nan":
    pool_member3 = ""
elif member3 != "nan":
    pool_member3 = member3 + ":" + pool_port3 + " "
else:
    pass
if member4 == "nan":
    pool_member4 = ""
elif member4 != "nan":
    pool_member4 = member4 + ":" + pool_port4 + " "
else:
    pass


if lb_mode_input == "Round Robin":
    lb_mode = "load-balancing-mode round-robin "
elif lb_mode_input == "Least connections":
    lb_mode = "load-balancing-mode least-connections-node "
elif lb_mode_input == "Observed":
    lb_mode = "load-balancing-mode observed-node "
else:
    pass

if monitor_input == "TCP":
    monitor = "monitor tcp "
elif monitor_input == "TCP 30 seconds":
    monitor = "monitor tcp-30 "
elif monitor_input == "Self-Service":
    monitor = "monitor self-service "
elif monitor_input == "None":
    monitor = ""
else:
    monitor = " monitor " + input("Please enter the health monitor name: ") + " "

member = IPAddress(member1)

# Lists for each LB pair containing the node subnets.
loadbalancer1_node_IPs = IPSet([IPNetwork('1.1.1.0/22'), IPNetwork('2.2.2.0/22'), IPNetwork('3.3.3.0/22')])
loadbalancer2_node_IPs = IPSet([IPNetwork('4.4.4.0/23'), IPNetwork('2.2.2.0/23'), IPNetwork('3.3.3.0/23')])

# Provides the LB the VIP is to be built on based on node IP address.
if IPAddress(member) in loadbalancer1_node_IPs:
    loadbalancer = "The LB pair you need to build this VIP on is loadbalancer1_node_IPs"
    subnet = "You need a VIP ip from subnet 1.1.1.0/22, 2.2.2.0/22, or 3.3.3.0/22"
elif IPAddress(member) in loadbalancer2_node_IPs:
    loadbalancer = "The LB pair you need to build this VIP on is loadbalancer2_node_IPs"
    subnet = "You need a VIP ip from subnet 4.4.4.0/23, 2.2.2.0/23, or 3.3.3.0/23"
else:
    pass

print(loadbalancer)
print(fqdn)
print(subnet)

vip_ip_input = IPAddress(input("Which VIP IP did you choose? "))
vip_ip = str(vip_ip_input) + str(":") + str(service_port_input)
ip = str(vip_ip_input)

if iRule1_input == "_sys_https_redirect":
    iRule1 = "_sys_https_redirect "
elif iRule1_input == "x-Forwarding":
    iRule1 = "x-forwarding "
else:
    iRule1 = ""
if iRule2_input == "_sys_https_redirect":
    iRule2 = "_sys_https_redirect "
elif iRule2_input == "x-Forwarding":
    iRule2 = "x-forwarding "
else:
    iRule2 = ""

if snat_input == "Auto Map":
    snat = "snat automap "
else:
    snat = ""

if one_connect_input == "oneconnect":
    one_connect = "oneconnect "
else:
    one_connect = ""

if http_profile_input == "http":
    http_profile = "http "
else:
    http_profile = ""

if primary_persist_input == "Source Addr":
    primary_persist = " persist replace-all-with { source_addr } "
elif primary_persist_input == "Dest Addr":
    primary_persist = " persist replace-all-with { dest_addr } "
elif primary_persist_input == "Cookie":
    primary_persist = " persist replace-all-with { cookie } "
else:
    primary_persist = ""

if fallback_persist_input == "Source Addr":
    fallback_persist = " fallback-persistence source_addr "
elif fallback_persist_input == "Dest Addr":
    fallback_persist = " fallback-persistence dest_addr "
elif fallback_persist_input == "Cookie":
    fallback_persist = " fallback-persistence cookie "
else:
    fallback_persist = ""

folder = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\LBARF script' + str(change_order)

createfolder(folder)

fh = open(folder + "/" + str(change_order) + ".txt", "w")
fh.write("This program is a test. I assume no responsibility." + "\r" +
         "Please verify everything looks correct." + "\r" + "\r" + "This script was run on " +
         x.strftime("%x") + " @ " + x.strftime("%I") + ":" + x.strftime("%M") + " " + x.strftime("%p") +
         " for change order " + change_order + "\r" + "\r" + fqdn + "\r" + ip + "\r" + loadbalancer + "\r" + "\r")

fh.write("create ltm pool " + pool_name + " members add { " + pool_member1 + pool_member2 + pool_member3 +
         pool_member4  + " } " + monitor + lb_mode + description + "\r" + "\r")

if service_port_input == "80 and 443":
    service_port_input = "80"
else:
    pass

if service_port_input == "80":
    if iRule1_input == "_sys_https_redirect":
        port_80_redirect_vip = ("create ltm virtual " + fqdn + "-80 destination " + ip +
                                ":80 profiles add { http } snat automap rules { _sys_https_redirect } "
                                + description + "\r" + "\r")
        fh.write(port_80_redirect_vip)
        print("Port 80 VIP is complete, We will now move on to the 443 VIP")
        service_port_input = "443"
        irules = "rules { " + iRule2 + " } "
    elif iRule2_input == "_sys_https_redirect":
        port_80_redirect_vip = ("create ltm virtual " + fqdn + "-80 destination " + ip +
                                ":80 profiles add { http } snat automap rules { _sys_https_redirect } "
                                + description + "\r" + "\r")
        fh.write(port_80_redirect_vip)
        print("Port 80 VIP is complete, We will now move on to the 443 VIP")
        service_port_input = "443"
        irules = "rules { " + iRule2 + " } "
    else:
        vip_build = ("create ltm virtual " + fqdn + "-" + service_port_input + " destination " + ip + ":" +
                     service_port_input + " pool " + pool_name + " profiles add { " + http_profile + " } " +
                     primary_persist + fallback_persist + description + "\r" + "\r")
        fh.write(vip_build)
        service_port_input = "443"
else:
    pass

if iRule1.__contains__("sys"):
    rules = "rules { " + iRule2 + " } "
elif iRule2.__contains__("sys"):
    rules = "rules { " + iRule1 + " } "
else:
    rules = "rules { " + iRule1 + iRule2 + " } "

if service_port_input == "443":
    ssl_profile_input = input("Will you be applying an SSL profile? y or n: ").lower()
    if ssl_profile_input.__contains__("y"):
        cert = input("Installing a cert? y or n: ").lower()
        if cert.__contains__("y"):
            ssl_profile_name = fqdn + "-clientssl"
            upload_name = fqdn + "-" + x.strftime("%Y")
            print("**** SSL PROFILE CONFIG *****")
            print("**** Upload Cert/Key to " + loadbalancer + " with the name of " + upload_name)
            ssl_cert = fqdn + "-" + x.strftime("%Y") + ".crt "
            ssl_key = fqdn + "-" + x.strftime("%Y") + ".key "
            chain_input = input("Will a chain be applied? y or n: ").lower()
            if chain_input.__contains__("y"):
                chain = " chain " + input("What is the name of the chain? ")
            else:
                chain = ""
            ciphers_input = input("Will ciphers be applied? ").lower()
            if ciphers_input.__contains__("y"):
                ciphers = "ciphers " + input("Enter Ciphers here: ")
            else:
                ciphers = ""
            ssl_config = ("create ltm profile client-ssl " + ssl_profile_name + " cert " + ssl_cert + " key " +
                          ssl_key + ciphers + " " + chain + description + "\r" + "\r")
        else:
            ssl_profile_name = input("What is the SSL profile name? ")
    else:
        ssl_profile_name = ""
        cert = ""
        key = ""
        chain = ""
        ciphers = ""
        ssl_config = ""
else:
    ssl_profile_name = ""
    cert = ""
    key = ""
    chain = ""
    ciphers = ""
    ssl_config = ""

profile = "profiles add { " + one_connect + http_profile + ssl_profile_name + " } "
if profile == "profiles add {  } ":
    profiles = ""
else:
    profiles = ("profiles add { " + one_connect + http_profile + ssl_profile_name + " } ")
    options = (profiles + snat + primary_persist + fallback_persist + rules + description)

if cert.__contains__("y"):
    fh.write(ssl_config)
else:
    pass

fh.write("create ltm virtual " + fqdn + "-" + service_port_input + " destination " + ip + ":" + service_port_input +
         " pool " + pool_name + " " + options + "\r" + "\r")
fh.close()

key_files = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/*.key'
crt_files = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/*.crt'
cer_files = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/*.cer'
pem_files = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/*.pem'
pfx_files = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/*.pfx'
filelist = glob.glob(key_files)

for single_file in filelist:
    shutil.move(single_file, folder)
filelist = glob.glob(crt_files)

for single_file in filelist:
    shutil.move(single_file, folder)

filelist = glob.glob(cer_files)
for single_file in filelist:
    shutil.move(single_file, folder)

filelist = glob.glob(pem_files)
for single_file in filelist:
    shutil.move(single_file, folder)

filelist = glob.glob(pfx_files)
for single_file in filelist:
    shutil.move(single_file, folder)

# os.rename(lbarf_file, 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/' + change_order + ".xlsx")
shutil.move(lbarf_file, folder)
print("The CLI commands for this VIP are located at " + folder)
exit(input("Press Enter to exit."))
```

It was suggested to me to put the script as a function and import it to the code for the GUI which I did and named it vipTest. Next I imported it to PySimpleGUI I am using to create a simple form with here:

```
import vipTest
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Very basic form.  Return values as a list
form = sg.FlexForm('VIP Builder')  # begin with a blank form

layout = [
          [sg.Text('Please enter the information below')],
          [sg.Text('What is the change order for this VIP?: ', size=(30, 1)), sg.InputText('change #')],
          [sg.Text('Enter the full path of the LBARF form: ', size=(30, 1)), sg.InputText('location path')],
          [sg.Text('Which VIP IP did you choose?: ', size=(30, 1)), sg.InputText('ip address of vip')],
          [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
         ]

lbarf_file, folder = vipTest.createfolder(directory)

button, values = form.Layout(layout).Read()
```

I am having trouble getting an output from the GUI of the results. When I run this program in PyCharm the GUI does not open and script runs in the console. Even if I can get the GUI to work with a specific example, I am concerned I might need to have the GUI add a text field each time the information in the excel file is blank. I would like to ultimately like to display the config commands from the gui but am not getting anywhere with it as is. Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend cutting down the code you shared to the minimal possible version that exemplifies your problem. It's quite long at the moment. During the process of cutting it down, you might even figure out the problem

Comment: @EmrahDiril I edited the code as you suggested but it is not making it easier for me unfortunately.

Comment: I removed the line "lbarf_file, folder = vipTest.createfolder(directory)" and the GUI displayed fine.  I ran it using PyCharm as well.  I guess I don't understand the problem as stated "I am having trouble getting an output from the GUI of the results.".  Not sure what that means..  Also, the PySimpleGUI code you're trying to use is extremely old.  The code doesn't look like that anymore.  FlexForm was replaced over a year ago.  Not sure where you're getting the examples from.  Try http://www.PySimpleGUI.org.